# Why does this code freeze when i try to plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The very last print statement is executed so it runs until the matplotlib command is called and then freezes. It is only about 40k rows of data.

````
import pandas as pd


df=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Path/Book1.csv")

vsd_stat = []

get_data = df

for i in range(len(get_data)):
    if get_data["Value"][i] is not None:   #check for empty value field first to stop program crashing
        if get_data["Value"][i] < 98.5:    #vsd active when tag <98.5
            vsd_stat.append([1, get_data["DateTime"][i]])        #1 = vsd on 0 = off
            print(i)
        else:
            vsd_stat.append([0, get_data["DateTime"][i]])
            print(i)
    else:
        print("Empty")
print("done")        
vals=[]
dates=[]

for i in range(len(vsd_stat)):
    vals.append(vsd_stat[i][0])

for i in range(len(vsd_stat)):
    dates.append(vsd_stat[i][1])

print("doe agaib")
matplotlib.pyplot.plot(dates,vals)```
````

Comment: That's a lot of data for a plot, isn't it? Maybe you want to preprocess the data and have a number of rows suitable for a plot.

Comment: @KlausD. Hmm, I thought that would be trivial for matplotlib since its 40k rows x 3 columns. I've done much larger datasets before in <10 seconds but this script has been running for over 20 minutes.

Comment: Maybe your dates are treated as strings. Then matplotlib would generate 40k x-tick labels. Quite the task to plot them. Check `df.info()` for the type of your date column. Besides, there must be better ways to filter pandas dataframes than using a for loop.

Comment: As per above, but also are you sure this is matplotlib fault?  You have a bunch of loops where you are appending to lists - appending to lists is very slow.

Comment: Yep @JodyKlymak. That's why I added all those print statements, to check where it was getting stuck. It was in the last line

Comment: Right, well as said above, if your data are strings, Matplotlib treats each value as a "category" and gives each one a tick.  Make sure they are not strings before passing to Matplotlib. https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/users/faq/howto_faq.html#why-do-i-have-so-many-ticks-and-or-why-are-they-out-of-order